# Y is path connected iff $f,g$ are null homotopic then f,g are homotopic

Tags: general-topology, path-connected

I have to show that $Y$ is path-connected if and only if: if X is any topological space and  $f,g: X\to Y$ are nullhomotopic, then $f,g$ are homotopic.

I understand that if Y is path-connected then $f,g$ are homotopic, but how can I show the other direction.

Couldn't we just add a single point to $Y$ so that it's not path-connected?

Comment: Yes, but you'd be adding more pairs $(X,f)$ such that $f:X\to Y$ continuous too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the other direction take $X=\{pt\}$ for two point $x,y \in Y$ define the maps 
$f_1(pt)=x$ and $f_2(pt)=y$. From this conclude that $Y$ is path connected.
For any other space $X$ just take constant maps.

If we add another point $pt'$ to $Y$ then we will have another map $f'(pt)=pt'$ and this map won't be homotopic to any other map